# Obtaining highest negative value to end of data

Tags: python, numpy

HI i have thousand of data inside an array. I am able to obtain first data - largest negative value(10 to-11) How can i obtain the largest negative value till the data ends??

```
Field = [10, 5, 0, -5, **-11, -8, -5, 0, 5, 15]**
```

How can i obtain the range of largest negative value to the end of data?

## Example of getting the range of first value to largest negative value

I am able to get 10 to -10 by using this method

```
P-NIP = Field[:Field.index(min(Field)) + 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you're asking.

Are you just asking for `x[x.argmin():]`?

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array([5, -1, 3, -11, -9, 2, -10])

In [3]: x[x.argmin():]
Out[3]: array([-11,  -9,   2, -10])
```

If you have a list instead of an array, you just do `x[x.index(min(x)):]` similar to the example you showed. For a numpy array, however, it's more efficient to use `argmin`.

Answer (score 1):

You've apparently got some numpy-answers.

I'll point out that if you want to find a minimum or maximum of a large collections of numbers, it's often better to use a tree, heap or treap instead of a linear list/array.

The Python Standard Library includes a heapq (heap) module.  I have a treap implementation here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treap/ , and a red black tree implementation here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/red-black-tree-mod/

In short, finding the least value in a large list is O(n), while finding the least value in a heap can be O(1), finding the least value in a treap is O(logn) and finding the least value in a red-black tree is O(logn).  However, the heap won't work for a max value at the same time it does for a minimum value - the treap and red-black tree will.  There's also something called a min-max heap that's O(1) time for both min and max, but I've not seen one implemented in Python.